# Comparing technical limitations of major quantum computing approaches

Tags: resource-request, superconducting-quantum-computing, optical-quantum-computing, quantum-optics, ion-trap-quantum-computing

As far as I know, major quantum computing approaches include superconducting qubits, trapped ions, nuclear magnetic resonance qubits, and free space quantum optics. I guess two main technical difficulties in this field are creating entanglement and maintaining entanglement.

Are there any introductory review articles address the state-of-the-art status of various quantum computing approaches as well as **the major challenges that each of them faces**.
Additionally, I am curious why the free-space quantum optics approach hasn't yet been "upgraded" to on-chip nanophotonic devices.

- I am a newbie to quantum computing research/industry. So, if there are any other promising approaches or other important technical difficulties, please add them.

Answer (score 3):

For a general overview about hardware and the difficulties they present, I recommend section three of [*Quantum Computing: An Overview Across the System Stack*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.07240). Another good introduction would be [*Quantum Computing Hardware Implementation Methods: A Survey over Categories*](http://khaledelleithy.org/Conferences/Quantum%20Computing%20Hardware%20Implementation%20Methods____.pdf).

Let me also give you some papers specific to certain implementations and their recent advancements.

Superconducting qubits:

- [*New material platform for superconducting transmon qubits with coherence times exceeding 0.3 milliseconds*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-22030-5).
- [*Superconducting Qubits: Current State of Play*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13641).

Trapped ion qubits:

- [*Realization of real-time fault-tolerant quantum error correction*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07505). This one may not be 100% about the hardware itself, but it still is a really important achievement using this technology.

NMR qubits:

- [*Quantum Computing and Nuclear Magnetic Resonance*](https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0106/0106067.pdf).

Topoligcal qubits:

- [*Understanding potential topological quantum bits*](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2021/07/210701140937.htm). Not exactly a paper but an interesting article on the journey of this technology.