# What are introductory resources to learn about quantum computing hardware?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization

I am interested in learning some details of quantum computers inner working, what are the limitation etc. in order to understand quantum computation more. Can some one refer me to some good materials in this regard? I have a PhD in theoretical physics, so technical documents won't be an issue.

Comment: What type of hardware you interested in? If you are looking at superconducting qubits then this might be a good "A Quantum Engineer’s Guide to Superconducting Qubits"   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06560.pdf

Comment: As well as this, "Tutorial: Gate-based superconducting quantum computing",   https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.08021

Comment: Okay will go thru these. Why don't you answer instead of commenting ?

Comment: [This answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18606/16092) might be of interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are **some** useful materials with respect to **superconducting qubits** that I found to be helpful:

1. **[A Quantum Engineer’s Guide to Superconducting Qubits](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06560.pdf)**, P. Krantz, M. Kjaergaard, F. Yan, T.P. Orlando, S. Gustavsson, and W. D. Oliver
2. **[Tutorial: Gate-based superconducting quantum computing](http://arxiv.org/abs/2009.08021)**, Sangil Kwon, Akiyoshi Tomonaga, Gopika Lakshmi Bhai, Simon J. Devitt, Jaw-Shen Tsai
3. **[Superconducting Quantum Computing: A Review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.10433.pdf)**, He-Liang Huang,Dachao Wu, Daojin Fan, Xiaobo Zhu
4. **[Superconducting Qubits:  A Short Review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0411174.pdf)**, M. H. Devoret, A. Wallraff, and J. M. Martinis
5. **[Superconducting Qubits and the Physics ofJosephson Junctions](https://copilot.caltech.edu/documents/16821/leshouchesjunctionphysics.pdf)** , John M. Martinis and Kevin Osborne
6. **[Superconducting Qubits: Current State of Play](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13641)**. Morten Kjaergaard, Mollie E. Schwartz, Jochen Braumüller, Philip Krantz, Joel I-Jan Wang, Simon Gustavsson, William D. Oliver
7. **[Fast, Accurate State Measurement in Superconducting Qubits](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/theses/Sank2014.pdf)** PhD thesis of Daniel Sank

The next best thing is to follow the work of the experts in the area of superconducting qubits, like [John Martinis](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/), [Robert Schoelkopf](https://rsl.yale.edu/), and many others . Go through the theses from their students.

Answer (score 2):

It largely depends on the technology you're interested in. If you want to learn about photonic quantum computing you can check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7iAqcFCTQQ) which summarizes very well how it works. If you want to learn more then I would suggest going to the Strawberry Fields website, specially this [page](https://strawberryfields.ai/photonics/hardware/details.html). Also going through the demos and tutorials is a great way to get a better understanding of how this works.

I hope this helps!