# What level of physics and math do I need to get into Quantum Computing (hardware)?

Tags: experimental-realization, computational-models, hardware

I already understand the abstractions of Quantum Computing (software), which includes qubits, interference, qubit entanglement, and circuits. However, despite being able to write Q# code that makes up a circuit, I don't have any understanding of the background math that supports Shor's Algorithm, Grover's Search, and algorithms as such.

However, what background knowledge do I need to understand the **physics and math** behind all these circuits? (as I can't fool myself to ignore my curiosity) In addition to understanding the **physical hardware architecture** of quantum computing to get into the computer "building" industry? I have taken Calculus 2 and Physics 1, what else?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21282/55

Comment: Linear algebra for sure